# Is there a size limitation/problem when writing the apache arrow format with the java API

Tags: java, limit, apache-arrow

My arrow writer reading data from CSV files works fine for data less 1 GB, but stucks at about this limit (the writing code seems to block). I have enough memory given to the process (-Xmx12g) and the data size is about 1.2GB. A similar structured file with less rows and approx 0.4 GB works fine with the same code.

I am just interested to know, if apache arrow currently has some limitations for the vectors created or limitations in the number of rows.

Answer (score 3):

It would be good to clarify how exactly it is failing (I assume you are seeing an exception).  But to address the question.

Currently, each Buffer that comprises a vector has a 2GB limit.  In addition all Arrow Vectors currently use an `int` index, so the there is a row limit of 2^31-1.  Due to how the default allocation process works (doubling of buffer sizes), the you might be getting close to the actual limit without preallocating.

The best practice for Arrow in general and Java in particular is to create small batches (e.g. read N rows convert them to a batch and write them out again, instead of trying to read the whole file). An example of this approach is viewable in the recently refactored [JDBC adaptor](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/java/adapter/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/arrow/adapter/jdbc/ArrowVectorIterator.java).

There has been [recent discussion](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/arrow-dev/201908.mbox/%3CCAK7Z5T_pvzhWwNpcvm_KyeL8ZXjNK11_T_5Zx5Whs7zL34O-tw%40mail.gmail.com%3E) on the developer mailing list for changing the API to support 64-bit indexing/sizes.

Comment: Thanks for this - I actually found out that I indeed get a memory overflow when  doubling:


org.apache.arrow.memory.OutOfMemoryException: Unable to allocate buffer of size 134217728 due to memory limit. Current allocation: 2016947468


But do I need to use just one allocator for all column vectors or can I use one allocator per column? The JDBC example you mentioned also shows just one allocator for the whole process. If not, it would mean I am limited to 2 GB total memory usage? Or do I miss something here?

Comment: I could solve the problem: The allocator takes an argument for maximum size and it was set to Integer.MAX_VALUE, which I copied from some examples and assumed (falsely) it is the maximum allowed. Actually it is possible to set this to a larger value and after that my reader worked fine with the larger file.

Comment: The jdbc example was illustrating creating smaller batches, most of the code is constructed assuming a single allocator pee vector.